# Change highlighting of results in the FitNesse wiki

Tags: fitnesse

Currently the output looks like
[image]

Is there a way to make the comparison all or nothing without making some custom style or comparator or some other plugin?

Comment: Also, this is using cslim

Answer (score 0):

If you mean out of the box, the answer is no. There is no setting for the highlighting of the differences. There could be a plugin changing this, but I haven't found it yet.

So if you really want it changed, you will have to dive into the source.

Comment: What about turning off all red highlighting.  I just want that horrible looking break in highlighting to be gone

Answer (score 0):

You can change the styles in `fitnesse_wiki.css`. The output is formatted with the classes `fail` and `diff`. Here's a sample of the output (not yours):

```
[10-Oct-197<span class="diff">4</span>] <span class="fail">expected [10-Oct-197</span><span class="diff">5</span><span class="fail">]</span>
```